# How to send local storage data with ajax to php page?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have stored form data in local storage array and i want to send that array with ajax to php page and also want to access data in php page.
Here is my code -

```
    var myvalue=document.getElementById('name').value;        
                    var favorites_str = localStorage.getItem('my_favorites');    
                    if(favorites_str == null) {    
                    favorites = [];      
                    favorites.push({ "name":myvalue});      
                    }    
         else{      
                    favorites = JSON.parse(favorites_str);      
                    favorites.push({ "name":myvalue});      
                    }  
             localStorage.setItem('my_favorites',JSON.stringify(favorites));      
    var data = localStorage.getItem('my_favorites');      
                    if(data == null){      
                    alert("0 favorites");      
                    }else{      
                    favorites = JSON.parse(data);      
                    $.each(favorites, function(index,item){      
                    var my_items=item.name;         
                    })      
                    };    
if(navigator.onLine)    
                 {  
                     $.ajax({  
                         url:'http://localhost/offline/nextpage.php',  
                         type:'post',  
                         data:{my_items:my_items},  
                         success:function(data)  
                         {  
                           $('#result').html(data);  
                         }  
                     });  
                 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have edited my code. I had forgotten to add ajax code.

Comment: Why don't you just convert the JSON array to string and send it to php and use `json_decode()` to read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you stored data in local storage with key name: "name" and you can get it like below and can send it into ajax call.

```
data: {name: localStorage.getItem('name')}
```

Comment: I don't see how you answered the question

Comment: I just hint like how he can pass the data in ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I can see in your code is that you are trying to send a variable (`my_items`) at the ajax request but the variable is defined in a different scope.

Try this instead:

```
var myvalue=document.getElementById('name').value; 
...
favorites = JSON.parse(data);
var my_items = [];
$.each(favorites, function(index,item){
    my_items.push(item.name);
});

if(navigator.onLine) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost/offline/nextpage.php',
        type:'post',
        data:{my_items:my_items},
        success:function(data)
        {
           $('#result').html(data);
         }
     });
 }
```

Now the `my_items` object is going to be accessible inside the ajax request.